# How can I create a keystore using an existing CSR file?

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl

I have a website in GoDaddy (Apache) and an application in Amazon AWS (Apache Tomcat).

**Website domain (apache): example.com**

**Application domain (apache tomcat): sub.example.com**

I know how to install the certificate for example.com in GoDaddy, I use this application to generate the CSR and Private Key:

https://www.rapidsslonline.com/ssl-tools/csr-generator.php

I copy the CSR to request the certificate and finally install it fine using the private key.

I know how to install the certificate in tomcat for sub.example.com creating a keystore then requesting the signature using the csr of the keystore generated and finally downloading the certificate and installing it, that's easy.

But I have a problem, **I can use only one solution : Install the website certificate or install the tomcat certificate, but not both.** Why? Because the CSR generated by the generator is different of the generated by the keystore, and I need the private key (that the generator gives).

Then, that's the reason of my question, how can I create a keystore using an existing CSR file?

Well my idea is to create the keystore using that CSR file (maybe exists a parameter for keytool), then using it to generate a new certificate. After this I can install in Apache and tomcat, How can I do it?

Maybe another solution is how to get the Private Key of a keystore, it will works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it by myself:

I don't use the generator, simply created the keystore with keytool and after that:

```
keytool 
-importkeystore -srckeystore <keystorefile> 
-destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 
-srcalias <jkskeyalias> -srcstorepass <passwordhere> 
-srckeypass <passwordhere>  -deststorepass <passwordhere> 
-destkeypass <passwordhere>
```

Then convert the keystore.p12 to private key file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out private.key
```

I get this:

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: tomcat
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 35 30 34 38 30 37 33 30 31 31 37 34 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQCgd4Hed6e2ArVx
bptp6zJDaAKOy4rWe4SHkjuWO7wgcxx4YoMARiIc2/xs070csTLCPXCmH+XtjX5Z
...
ej4hBu/2Bhv1QfH24gRKwHDsBAtQEa6nEn+LwPklgh5KbjY2ocSh6LIQEP4b+4CU
yneEbq6rJS6QLIhxgkEFZO6Jcw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not make sense as stated. None of this involves a CSR file. You can't import a CSR into a keystore as far as I know, and the operation makes no sense even if you could.

What really happened is that you received a PFX file, which is already a keystore, and already contains keypair, signed certificate, and CA chain. You can use that file directly as a PKCS#11 keystore in Java, or else import the entire thing into a JKS keystore with the `keytool`.

You could have *started from* a keystore, by generating a keypair and a CSR. You could then have got it signed and received a signed certificate and CA chain. You would then import those things into the keystore using the same alias as you did when generating the keypair.

Comment: The point is that the keytool command that generates a csr (certificate request) writes some representation of the csr to the keystore. If someone for what ever reason renews/replaces the keystore you lose being able to use the signed crt file unless there is some way to write the csr representation back into the new keystore.

Comment: @Keir No, it doesn't 'write some representation of the CSR to the keystore`. It writes it to a file which you then send to a CA and get a signed certificate in return. If someone replaces the keystore, an act of grade A stupidity which you must ensure cannot happen or is recoverable from, you have lost the private key, and it is that which prevents you from using the signed certificate that matches it.